# Two minimization problems using singular value decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, statistics

Posted here too: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234392/two-minimization-problems-using-singular-value-decomposition

Let $q_0, q_1:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be two maps whose components are $L^2[0,1]$, i.e. $q_0, q_1 \in L^2([0,1],\mathbb{R}^n)$. Denote by $||.||$ the Euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the following two minimization problems:

1) minimize $\int_{0}^{1} || q_0(t) - A q_1(t) ||^2 dt $ over $A \in SO(n)$.

2) Consider $U \subset L^2([0,1],\mathbb{R}^n)$ to be the unit sphere in $L^2([0,1],\mathbb{R}^n)$. Let $q_0, q_1 \in U$ now. Then $Aq_1 \in U$ as well for any $A \in SO(n)$. Consider the geodesic  $c(A)$ in $U$ joining $q_0, Aq_1$. 
Minimize the length of $c(A)$.

How can we solve these two problems with/without, preferably with, using **singular value decomposition**? It was mentioned in the paper http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=5601739

But I'd appreciate a detailed explanation for solving these two problems.

Answer (score 1):

The first question is easy, at least in theory. When $A\in SO(n)$,
$$
\|q_0(t)-Aq_1(t)\|^2=\|q_0(t)\|^2 + \|q_1(t)\|^2 - 2\operatorname{tr}\left(Aq_1(t)q_0(t)^T\right).
$$
So, if we set $M=\int_0^1q_1(t)q_0(t)^Tdt$, you only need to minimise $- 2\operatorname{tr}(AM)$. Therefore the minimiser is $A=V\operatorname{diag}\left(1,\ldots,1,\det(VU^T)\right)U^T$, where $USV^T$ is a singular value decomposition of $M$ with the singular values arranged in descending order on the diagonal of $S$.